# Android HttpPost and Multithreading a few issue

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http-post

I have an Android application that makes a post request to my .NET Web Api. It works fine but I need some updates to provide better service to user. And this leading some problems for me.

I have username, password textboxes and login button in activity_main.xml file.

When user click the login button, I am checking the values, then if they are appropriate I send them to server via my WebRequest.java class.

Here is my problem:

When I am sending these values to server, my main (UI) thread is locking. I wanted to prevent that locking using Thread:

```
public static WebLoginResponse loginRequest(final String username, final String password) {
    Thread loginThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // making request here.
        }
    });
    loginThread.start();
}
```

That prevents locking but response returns null. It's clear why is that. Because when I call this method from my MainActivity.java file like:

```
WebLoginResponse response = WebRequests.loginRequest(username, password);
```

**loginThread** running the loginRequest but UI thread came back from loginRequest method and trying to get values of **response** variable. **loginThread** has not finished its job yet, that's why response is null.

And this is not the solution of my problem because response always be null.

Finally, I want to do this request but not to locking UI thread.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is a well known pattern in asynchronous programming, named usually **promises**, **futures** or **delay**.

For a general discussion of the pattern, see: [Wikipedia: Futures and promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)

In Java, have a look at the [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface, a very good tutorial on this and Java concurrency in general can be found at [Lars Vogel's blog](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform you web access request on a background thread. Personally, I use an `AsyncTask`.

Here are a few links:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
- [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)
- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

And here is some sample code which will need work:

```
private WebLoginTask mWebLoginTask = null;

public static WebLoginResponse loginRequest(final String username, final String password) {
    mWebLoginTask = new WebLoginTask();
    mWebLoginTask.execute();
}

private class WebLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (this.isCancelled() == true) { return null; }

        // ..... do your web stuff here .....
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void success) {
        // ..... do stuff here when the web stuff is finished ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do I have to write these codes to my activity.java file? Otherwise, I cannot use context, controls etc. I want to realize it on my WebRequests.java class. How can I?

Comment: Yes, you include the `AsyncTask` in your main `class` file. There are plenty of examples here on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=aysnctask

Comment: It sounds like makes no sense at all. Isn't it against to 3 layered architecture? If I have web request, I should do it in my WebRequest.java file. I should seperate operations by their doings. Isn't it?